# Is it possible to set SonarQube to analyse the JSON files?

Tags: java, json, sonarqube

Some funcionalities of my software have their complexity on json files, which contain the metadata that is used on them.
So, it would be extremelly important that SonarQube analyse this files.

Does anybody know if it is possible?

Thanks, Guilherme

Comment: I don't know SonarQube much, but I know there is an online version; is that what you use or do you run it locally?

Comment: I'll explain why I say that; if you can program your own rule, you can use a JSON Schema to check the correctness of your JSON. There are however limits in what it can validate, but you can use [this implementation](https://github.com/fge/json-schema-validator) (yes, it's mine) which allows you to develop custom keywords if needed.

Comment: Thank you, @fge! I'll try it. Beside checking the correctness and performance, does it check the complexity? Is it possible for a json document?

Comment: I Would like to collect some metrics to get my software maintainability rank

Comment: Not sure what you mean by complexity? What would be a criterion?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is currently (SQ 5.0) no analyzer for JSON in SonarQube (neither in platform nor in plugins).

Comment: Sounds like we should make a plugin for it(a wrap over JSHint) :)

Comment: Thanks! I'll look for another way to add theses files in my measure.

Answer (score 1):

[SonarQube website](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Plugin+Library) now claims it has a plugin for JSON files.